# Installing Composer on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

I am planning to locally develop a front-end for Wordpress using React and Nextjs. I found out that [this git](https://github.com/postlight/headless-wp-starter) exists and how much trouble it would save me, so I decided on using it.

The installation requires setting up Docker, but does not go into depth about how to do this and the website does not seem to give much more information.

I guessed that [this version](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop) is probably what I want to download, however there isn't a link to download it for Linux systems.

How should I proceed here?

Docker-Composer doesn't seem to want to install correctly and I suppose that's because I don't have Docker installed.

I'm pretty confused and could really use some help to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu 16.04 and later composer can be installed from the default Ubuntu repositories. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install composer docker docker-compose
```

The above command installs Composer 1.7.2-1 on Ubuntu 18.10. It will also install the required PHP and JSON dependency packages along with it. Composer dependency manager for PHP helps you declare, manage and install dependencies of PHP projects, ensuring you have the right stack everywhere.

Running `docker-compose up -d` starts the containers in the background and leaves them running.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what this means, this installs composer but not Docker which is what the Github installation says I should install.

Comment: For the records, I installed this, but still can't run `docker-compose up -d` because Docker is not installed

Comment: This did install it but I cannot get the git installation to complete. Thank you for the help, I'll probably open a new thread for this new problem.